# how to pass parameter from many activity to one activity

Tags: android, android-activity

hey everyone, i am new in android

i have five activity's and one result activity
i want to send some data/parameter to result activity

first_activity,
sec_activity,
third_activity,
four_activity,
five_activityeach

each have some data like name and age

onclicking, i want the data to be saved/send to result_activity.
thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your data from each activity to [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), then acces it from your final activity. Here are some examples: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 1):

Why are they all separate activities in the first place? Should they be a part of a single-activity wizard instead? Here is a [recent blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/02/14/nature-activity.html) of mine that goes into somewhat more details.

Answer (score 0):

You do it throught Intents and use the putExtras methods

Comment: How are you opening one activity from another?

Comment: i simply use intent to result_activity

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what Marcos said, here'e a good place to start with Intents.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html